# Use Case in Datediff statement

Tags: mysql, sql, case, datediff

Could you please help me with the below query:
Consider these 2 tables for Car repair company:

```
Old_Value   New_Value   Created
0           1           2016/09/14
1           2           2016/09/15
2           3           2016/09/19

Value   Description
0       Not Diagnosed Yet
1       In Queue
2       In Progress
3       Fixed
```

I'm trying to calculate the Handle Time, which is the date difference between the "In Progress" and "Fixed" status:

```
Select 
datediff(day, (case when Old_Value='1' and New_Value='2' then Created else Null end), (case when Old_Value='2' and New_Value='3' then Created else Null end))
as Handle_Time
from tb1
```

All I'm getting is an error msg.
Any help please, thank you.

Comment: What is the expected result. Also `DATEDIFF` is `SQL SERVER` function

Comment: The expected result is an Integer format.
i.e. The Handle_time is 4 days. It's the date difference between when the status changed to "In Progress" and when it was changed to "fixed".
The result should be like:
_italic_ 
`Handle_Time
 
4`

Comment: Does the first table only have three rows?  If you have more rows, there is pretty much no way to figure out which values match.

Comment: Yes, it has only 3 rows.

Comment: Thank you for your help guys, that was quick.
@GordonLinoff

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In MySQL, you don't use `day`.  I would expect a query such as this:

```
Select repair_id,
       datediff(max(case when old_value = 1 and new_value = 2 then created end),
                max(case when old_value = 2 and new_value = 3 then created end)
               ) as handle_time
from tb1
group by repair_id;
```

I've invented the column `repair_id`, because it makes sense to me.  If the table only has one repair in it, you can leave it out of the query.

Answer (score 1):

Not clear what you want but try this it will return 4.

```
Select TOP 1
datediff(DAY, (SELECT CREATED FROM T1 WHERE New_Value = 2), (SELECT CREATED FROM T1 WHERE New_Value = 3)) as handle_time
from t1
```

AND I have just run your query but found no error. It just returned all 3 rows as NULL.

```
CREATE TABLE T1(Old_Value int, New_Value int, Created DATE)
CREATE TABLE T2(Value int, Description varchar(50))

INSERT INTO T1 VALUES
(0, 1, '2016/09/14'),
(1, 2, '2016/09/15'),
(2, 3, '2016/09/19')

INSERT INTO T2 VALUES
(0, 'Not Diagnosed Yet'),
(1, 'In Queue'),
(2, 'In Progress'),
(3, 'Fixed')

Select 
datediff(day, (case when Old_Value='1' and New_Value='2' then Created else Null end), (case when Old_Value='2' and New_Value='3' then Created else Null end))
as Handle_Time
from T1

DROP TABLE T1
DROP TABLE T2
```

Result:

```
Handle_Time
NULL
NULL
NULL
```

Now just run following query

```
Select 
(case when Old_Value='1' and New_Value='2' then Created else Null end) AS param1, 
(case when Old_Value='2' and New_Value='3' then Created else Null end) AS param2,
datediff(day, (case when Old_Value='1' and New_Value='2' then Created else Null end), (case when Old_Value='2' and New_Value='3' then Created else Null end))
as Handle_Time
from T1
```

Result:

```
param1      param2      Handle_Time
NULL        NULL        NULL
2016-09-15  NULL        NULL
NULL        2016-09-19  NULL
```

So in datediff one of your parameters are always null which returns null.

```
SELECT DateDiff(DAY, NULL, NULL) --return NULL
SELECT DateDiff(DAY, GETDATE(), NULL) --return NULL
SELECT DateDiff(DAY, NULL, GETDATE()) --return NULL
```